# Conditional formatting django css

Tags: python, css, django

I pretty new to Python and Django. My first Project is a MS Teams Status Call Monitor.
Its working so far. But I asked myself if its possible to format the Table different when having a change in my Status.

```
Available = Green
Away = Yellow
Busy = Red
```

How can I do that with Django / CSS?

```
{% extends "tutorial/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Teams</h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">Activity</th>
     <th scope="col">Availability</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ status.status }}</td>     
        <td>{{ status.availability }}</td>      
     </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please. Just. Use. Classes.

```html
<style>
.table td {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:#e9f032;
}
.table.available td {
    background-color:#179148;
}
.table.busy td {
    background-color:#ed1f1f;
}
</style>

<table class="table {{ status.availability|lower }}">
...
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Good Point. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var input = $('.input').text()
console.log(input)

if (input == 'Busy') {
    $('.input').css('color', 'red')
} else if (input == 'Away') {
    $('.input').css('color', 'yellow')
} else if (input == 'Available') {
    $('.input').css('color', 'green')
} else {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">Activity</th>
     <th scope="col">Availability</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td class="input">Available</td>     
     </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the end these Line of Code worked:

```
{% extends "tutorial/layout.html" %}    
{% block content %}
<style>

    {% if status.availability == 'Available' %}

    .table td{
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color:#179148;
    }

    {% elif status.availability == 'Busy' %}
        .table td{
             font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
             font-weight: bold;
             background-color:#ed1f1f;
        }
    {% else %}
        .table td{
             font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
             font-weight: bold;
             background-color:#e9f032;
        }
    {% endif %}
  </style>
<h1>Teams</h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th scope="col">Activity</th>
     <th scope="col">Availability</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ status.status }}</td>     
        <td>{{ status.availability }}</td>      
     </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding this to your code should solve the thing, of course, the important part here is the nested if statement not the CSS.

```
<style>
    {%if status.avilability == Available %}

    .table{
        color:green;
    }

    {% else %}

        {% if status.avilability == Busy %}
          .table{
             color:red;
          }
        {% else %}
          .table{
             color:yellow;
          }

    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

In the End I added this piece of code:

<style>

    {% if status.availability == Available %}
  
 .table td{
  background-color:green;
 }

    {% elif status.availability == Busy %}
        .tabel td{
             background-color:red;
        }
 {% else %}
        .table td{
             background-color:yellow;
        }
    {% endif %}
  </style>

However, now I always have a Yellow Background and it doesnt catch Available or Busy